# [Unable to find the socket transport "TLS" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #32673]

Tags: php, sockets, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-14.04, swiftmailer

I'm facing the following message when sending email through Zoho SMTP server.

> [Unable to find the socket transport "TLS" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #32673]

I tried looking for opennssl support on my PHP installation and it seems everything is OK.

My `phpInfo()` says that the TLS stream are registered and openssl extension enabled.

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on Ubuntu server 14.04 on Digital Ocean and PHP 5.6.20.
I google for a solution but I just found answers for Windows OS.

Comment: Resolved. I changed the option value MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS to lowercase in my .env file and it's all just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I changed the option value MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS to lowercase in my .env file and all just worked fine.

Comment: it tool me hours to find that!
Using Swiftmailer: "Unable to find the socket transport "TLS" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #38365528" - you have to write "tls" lower case…